# Localizar coluna e posicionar o cursor na mesma

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho uma planilha que contem:

```
COLUNA A1 CABECALHO (PRODUTOS)
COLUNAS B1 A BK1 COM DATAS
```

Vou ler um banco de dados ordenado por produto e data e tenho
    que automaticamente preencher na planilha pocisionando os valores de cada produto em suas respectivas datas.

```
PRODUTOS     01/10/2016   02/10/2016   03/10/2016 .......  30/10/2016
PRODUTO1                     R$ 1,00      R$ 2,00
PRODUTO2      R$ 5,00                                      R$ 10,00
```

Como localizar coluna e posicionar o cursor na mesma?
 Esqueci de informar, mas estou usando VBA por dentro do Excel como ferramenta de desenvolvimento.

Comment: O lance, é que eu vou criar a planilha através de uma seleção de data inicial e data final, então o usuário pode selecionar a partir de qualquer dia/mês/ano. Até aqui tudo certo, o problema é como saber posicionar nas datas certas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma opção seria:

Crie uma função para pegar a data que usuário quer e posicionar em cima da data:

```
Sub buscaData()

Dim DATA_ As String
Dim CELULA_ As Range
Dim RESPOSTA_ As Long



    DATA_ = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Qual a data desejada?", _
                Title:="BUSCAR DATA", Default:=Format(Date, "Short Date"), Type:=1)
    If DATA_ = "False" Then Exit Sub

    DATA_ = Format(DATA_, "Short Date")

    On Error Resume Next
        Set CELULA_ = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(DATA_), After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
            , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If CELULA_ Is Nothing Then
        RESPOSTA_ = MsgBox("Data não encontrada, deseja buscar outra data?", vbInformation + vbYesNo)
        If RESPOSTA_ = vbYes Then Run "buscaData":
    Else
        CELULA_.Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Função adaptada de http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-dates.htm

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Show de bola. 100%. Fiz um código muito loco. Vou ajeita-lo a minha necessidade. Estou pegando as datas em um form utilizando o dtpicker.

Comment: Cara. Deu problema. Ao executar o código, célula sempre retorna nothing.

Comment: Será porque as células estão com merge? BC, DE, FG, ...

Comment: Fiz algo de errado. Verifiquei e fiz bobagem. Agora está funcioando.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Qualquer coisa poste aqui. Abraço e sucesso!

Comment: Valeu muito sua ajuda. Gostei daqui.